# Document.write and Save to db with php

Tags: php, javascript, save

I was wondering if it is possible to save some data with PHP getting the value from a form placed in the page by javascript with `document.write`, the value of which has been set by javascript with `document.getElementbyId(id).value`.

I know that with `.innerHTML()` it doesn't work, since the save button doesn't get a value set with the `.innerHTML()` method.

So I was wondering, would it work if I have javascript place an input box with `document.write` and then its value is set by another js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you place the `<input>` inside a form.

Here is a simple example:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if( !empty( $_POST['hidden_input']))
{
    die( 'Value: ' . $_POST['hidden_input']);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write( '<input id="hidden_input" type="hidden" name="hidden_input" value="0" />');
</script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('hidden_input').value = 'Changed with JS';
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you think it would work also if I create th input fields with the createelement method? I realized that I might need to add elements also after the page has been loaded, so I can't rely on document.write...

Comment: You should never use `document.write` anyway! (Yes this will work. Form submission uses the DOM to find form controls, just like everything else.)